# Convert Android app to Blackberry smartphones and tablets

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

The android app reads from database but doesnt write anything to DB,
the app display a few web pages, and other simple things like list of search results...

Please note that I managed to convert the .apk file to .bar without any problems using BlackBerry automated tools, so, the code is compatible with Blackberry SDK. However, **I to need  create all necessary deployment files, .cod, .jad, .bar, etc**,

how can I do that? 
is it true that I need to re-write it?
I have imported the android project to Blackberry project and everything seems fine except **class R** it seems there is no class R in blackberry, what should I do to it?

To see the app on Android market https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hazcheck.dgl

to see the app on iTunes http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hazcheck-dgl-lite/id518643993

Thanks for your continuous help

Comment: Converting to BAR means that you can run it on PlayBook and future BB10. But not the BlackBerryies smartphones. So it will require some effort to port it to BB

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Thanks for your comment... From your experience, do I need to re-write the app from scratch to support it to BB earlier than BB10?

Comment: We already have several projects that use one domain model sdk and extensions specific to devices like network, storage, telephony, etc. And UI should be also written from scratch. Since it's already existed app for Android and quite simple I would start BB from scratch or trying to reuse some code from Android if it doesn't use classes and syntax from Java 5

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Thanks for your helpful comments, would you write it as answer so I can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to have domain model and other parts same for Android, BlackBerry and J2ME. But be aware that it should be compatible with java 1.3 so you could miss you sugar like new classes, reflection, annotations, etc. This also requires additional effort on design and support level. And the last point the UI and other platform depended parts should be written from scratch.

I would write BB app from beginning for your case because you're saying it's simple app and Android version is already finished.